# add new column in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array containing three columns like this:

```
data.push({
  country: new Date(),
    newSales: Math.random() * 1000,
     expenses: Math.random() * 5000
 });
```

Now, on button click, I want to add a new column in it. Can anyone let me know how we can do it?

Comment: If you want to add a new attribute in the first element of data try `data[0].newcolumnname = 'whatever value'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could iterate though the data array and add key & value to each element.

```
data[0]["foo"] = bar; // this can be useful if the key is not constant
```

or

```
data[0].foo = "bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define the columns in your array in a separate object like this:

```
var cols = { country: new Date(), newSales: Math.random() * 1000, expenses: Math.random() * 5000 };
```

Then say, 
    data.push(cols);

Now in your button logic, add a new column (or rather property) to the object as follows:

```
obj.newCol = 'some value';
```

This will then be automatically reflected in your array

Answer (score 1):

// Pseudocode

```
for i in data
    data[i].foo = "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

This my way to add column to 2 dimensional array.

I shared for whom concerned.

```
var textarray = [[{ text: 'Content 1' }, { text: 'Content 2' }], 
                 [{ text: 'Content 3' }, { text: 'Content 4' }]];
```

Method to add column to array in the right as

```
insertColumnAtRight() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.textarray.length; i++) {
      this.textarray[i].push({ text: "" });
    }
}
```

If you want to add column in the left, you can use `unshift` method instead of `push`.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the "push"-method: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Comment: If you see my code, I am already using push method to insert item. My question is how to add a new column in the array. not new item. Hope its clear now.